# Decimal point result shows differently

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, debugging

I have Amount filed and its data type is number(16,2). When I see that field value by SOQL in Developer console then its 1525.54, I use same query in trigger and I see that value by system.debug() then it is 1525.53000001.

Why same field value differently shows?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the relevant parts of your trigger code? Especially the api version, the query for the record, the debug statement, and anywhere else in that code that the record or field value is referenced. I would like to try reproducing this in my system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you have a typo, as the display value should be 1525.53, not 1525.54, given the underlying value of 1525.53000001.

Internally, salesforce.com stores *all numbers* as some binary value capable of expressing any legal value of 18 digits, ranging from 18.0 format (zero places after the decimal) to 1.17 (17 places after the decimal). Calculated values that are not rounded, such as dividing two arbitrary values can result in a value stored in the database that isn't limited to the configured precision of the field. I'm assuming they do this so that you can freely change the number of decimals without having to rewrite the entire database every time.

The system simply rounds those values to the nearest display value (e.g. 2 decimal places) when queried by most APIs. However, Apex Code will still see the originally stored value, particularly from a trigger. This means that it's entirely possible that what you see on the screen isn't the fully stored value that's in the field. For example, if you're calculating the percentage of some other value, then the amount displayed in the UI may very well not match the amount stored in the database. This is perfectly normal.

If you're calculating values and storing them into this field, and you want to discard the insignificant portion of the data, use the [Decimal.setScale](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm#apex_System_Decimal_setScale) function to limit the value to a number of significant decimal places.